# SVG xlink:href attribute does not obey xml:base

Tags: xml, svg, href

I have a piece of simple SVG file below. The **xml:base** is declared in root element but the **xlink:href** attribute does not follow it. The image URL is still based on document's base URL. How to fix the issue?

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xml:base="https://pathfinding-lab.azurewebsites.net/images"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="map" width="640" height="640">
    <!--Background-->
    <image x="0" y="0" width="32" height="32" xlink:href="tileGrass1.png"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/xml-base-attribute-has-been-deprecated/

Comment: @RobertLongson does that mean if I want to turn SVG element into standalone file, everything needs to be absolute URL?

Comment: Either absolute, or relative to the SVG's URL.